# что сделать с nav чтобы оно не двигалось при hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass, navigationbar

Здесь [ссылка](https://codepen.io/shprd95/pen/yrpyav) на кодпен, ячейки меню двигаются вниз при наведениии курсора. Как сделать так, чтобы они оставались на месте ?
Я добавил max-height, но это не помогло
*CSS*

```
  a:hover
    border-top: #4acaff solid 4px  
    max-height: 15px
```

p.s. использую bootstrap и sass

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте изначально для ссылки прозрачную границу сверху, чтобы при наведении граница не появлялась, а просто окрашивалась:

```
border-top: transparent solid 4px
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a
  border-top: 4px solid transparent
  max-height: 15px

a:hover
  border-top-color: #4acaff
```

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотри этот код](https://codepen.io/Andrey_Dobrin/pen/zXpvWp?editors=1100) - там я немного подправил. Может это тебе понравится)

`a.nav-link 
    text-decoration: none 
    margin: 0 32px 0 0
    border-top: 4px solid transparent
    transition: all .2s // You can delete this
    &:hover
        border-top-color: #4acaff`

Comment: Спасибо, но страница 404

Answer (score 0):

Используй **box-shadow** вместо **border-top**

```
box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 #4acaff;
```